# drupal 7, how to use variables inside THEME_file_link() function

Tags: theming

I have library website and site managers can upload the book and visitors will be able to download them. I list books in a page view of `library` content type and I need to have information and properties of the uploaded file (using drupal 7 default file field). this is my function to find the file properties:

```
function MYTHEME_file_link(&$variables) {
kpr($variables);
}
```

and this is one of the results

[image]

by this code

```
function MYTHEME_file_link(&$variables) 
{
    print $variables['file']->filename;
}
```

it prints the filename but

I tried this

```
function MYTHEME_file_link(&$variables) 
{
    $name = $variables['file']->filename;
        $variables['name'] = t("$name");
        $variables['name1'] = $name;
        $variables['test1'] = "1111";
        $variables['test2'] = t("2222");
}
```

and then these codes `<?php print $name."  ".$name1; ?>` and `<?php print $test1."  ".$test2; ?>` didn't output the values.

there are two pages, `page--library.tpl.php` which `library__view` is embedded inside it and `views-view-fields--library__view--page.tpl.php` I output variables inside `views-view-fields--library__view--page.tpl.php` page

why can't I use defined variables inside the `file_link()` function?

Comment: You can get all the properties in the view itself is there any reason you are doing this in the tpl?

Comment: @MohammedShameem how can I get all the properties? what are these properties name? how can I get the name and url?

Comment: I guess you had asked this question earlier. please check my answer in this link http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87935/file-field-properties-drupal7

Comment: im trying to find it in `link_file` function

Comment: any reason for doing that? if it is just adding a link then you can directly do that in the views.

Comment: yes there is reason. this is the way I can access it inside `THEME_preprocess_views_view_fields` for `i-th` book :  ['view']->result[`i-th`]->field_field_library_file[0]['raw']['uri'] I can't replace `i-th` with variable

Comment: you can add the fields as I mentioned in the other answer and you would get all the fields you want and you can add them and get them in the template file.

Comment: Could you fix a typo in your code first? Now obvious reason of failure seems to be `['file]` without closking `'` ;)

Comment: @Mołot it is ['file'] in my code

Comment: @Mohammad but not in your question. Please fix it, OK?